# StrongLoop and LoopBack: what is the difference between "$ slc run" and "$ slc start"?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I follow "Getting started with LoopBack" tutorial (http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Getting+started+with+LoopBack). And in the first step of the tutorial they start the app with `$ slc run` and on other steps they start the app with `$ slc start`. And they do not give explanation what is the difference between `run` and `start`.

And when I start my app with `$ slc start` the server doesn't start at all. Only `$ slc run` starts the server. Here is an output of `$ slc start` where nothing works:

```
C:\Users\user\sbox\strongloop\hello>slc start .
App `.` started under local process manager.
  View the status:  slc ctl status
  View the logs:    slc ctl log-dump
  More options:     slc ctl -h
```

And when I check the status, it says that it is stopped:

```
C:\Users\user\sbox\strongloop\hello>slc ctl status
manager:
  pid:                4764
  port:               8701
  base:               C:\Users\user\.strong-pm
current:
  status:             stopped
  link:               C:\Users\user\sbox\strongloop\hello
  current:            hello
  branch:             local-directory
  worker count:       0
```

And here is an example where they start the different ways:

1) http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Create+a+simple+API

Run the application:

```
$ slc run
```

2) http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Use+API+Explorer

Run the application:

```
$ slc start
```

3) ttp://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Connect+your+API+to+a+data+source

Now run the application:

```
$ slc start
```

5) http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Add+a+static+web+page

Run it....!

```
$ slc start
```

6) http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Add+a+custom+Express+route

Now, run the application again:

```
$ slc start
```

So, my questions are:

1) Why on the first step they used `$ slc run` and all other steps they used `$ slc start`?

2) What is the difference between `$ slc run` and `$ slc start`?

3) Is it a question for StrongLoop forum or is it a question for LoopbackJS forum? Because the tutorial I follow is located on http://docs.strongloop.com/ and is called "*Getting started with LoopBack*" and the command I run is `$ slc` (StrogLoop Controller). It is confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, you caught us in the midst of a documentation change.

You should generally use `node .` to run your loopback applications during development.

`slc run` is the supervisor. It is being replaced with the process manager. The supervisor did useful things (dynamic control of your app using CLI, automatic clustering, restart on failure, etc.), but it didn't do lots of other things we needed, such as dynamic app control using a UI, graphical cpu and heap profiling, metrics graphing, management of deployments, etc.

The process manager does all this, and it's UI is `slc arc`. `slc start` starts your app so that `slc arc` can interact with it.